# Relationship not working in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

i having two relationship model in my project.
CarPool & Ride & User.

In my CarPool model

```
public $with=['user','ride'];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function ride(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ride');
}
```

In my ride model

```
public $with=['user','carpool'];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function carpool(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarPool');
}
```

In my expected scenario, when user enter to "My Ride" page, it will display all ride took by user.(For example users took 3 rides).So the list having 3 column. Each ride column having carpool information and driver information.

In my controller, i use this to get the ride belongs to user.

```
$user_id=Auth::user()->id;

    $rides= Ride::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
```

But after i check the result. Seem like the carpool relationship has not connected because there was null. Is my relationship not correct?

[image]

My table in database
car_pools Table
[image]

rides Table
[image]

Comment: Can you post your table structure for both tables?

Comment: Are you sure that `Ride` have related with one `Carpool`? Please try `dd($rides[0]->carpool);`

Comment: @lan i updated my table ,please check

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn is return null value.

Comment: @Eann So please change your model relation: `public function carpool(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarPool');
}` to `public function carpool(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarPool', 'car_pool_id');
}`

Comment: still return null

Answer (score 1):

Problems solved, although is not eagle loading but still can work in another ways. I changed my ride model by removing the carpool. So now is

```
public $with=['user'];
```

Then i call the data by `{{ $ride->carpool->title }}`
Not same with my expectation but at least working.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you don't have `car_pool_id` fields in the `rides` table that has related CarPool ID in it.

If you have this fields, but the name is different, add the foreign key name to the relationship:

```
public function carpool()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarPool', 'custom_column_name');
}
```

Comment: Yes i have car_pool_id in my rides table. i uploaded my database table, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try after giving foreign-key and primary key both in the relation mapping function.
Because sometimes if you are just giving foreign key, Then the model will try to connect to the other model with its primary key. If you are not using the primary key for relation specify the other key in the relation function.